# Why is my Visual Studio Code terminal lagging and executing programs after a delay?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I am running my program, there is an approximately 5 seconds delay in running of program in my Visual Studio Code terminal. Is there a solution?

There is nothing wrong with my system configuration. It's 8 GB of RAM and I am running Windows 10 2020 Edition and it worked fine till now.

I am using Visual Studio Code version 1.58.2., and for a fact I noticed that the lag is not happening if I am running other programs.

Comment: whats your system configuration?

Comment: What operating system (incl. version)? What version of Visual Studio Code? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68603578/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it is happening by running all the programs.

And if no, then it may be your code which is slowing the process. And restart your PC. It may help.